# Array returning as an Object in React Native = can't reference an array item?

Tags: arrays, object, react-native

I'm using React Native and Open Weather Map API to build a small weather app.  The data I retrieve from the API call is more than I want to use so I parse out just the pieces I need and store them in an array.  I then take the array and set it to a state object.  I can reference the object, but instead of saying my array is an array, it says it's an object, and thus won't let me use any array methods on it.  How do I get around this?

```
//reponseData is the data retrieved from the API call; the data retrieved is an object with arrays and objects 
within.  The forecast data for the next five days is given in 3 hour increments, so you have a 40 item array of 
data pieces.  I loop through this list of 40 items, pull out just what I need...

let forecastArray = [];

for (let i=0; i<responseData.list.length; i++) {
    let day = responseData.list[i].date
    let high = responseData.list[i].weather[0].hiTemp
    let low = responseData.list[i].weather[0].loTemp
    let condition = responseData.list[i].sys.condition

    forecastArray.push(day)
    forecastArray.push(high)
    forecastArray.push(low)
    forecastArray.push(condition)

    this.setState({
        forecastData: forecastArray
    })
```

When I log, I get an array....

```
    console.warn("forecast is: ", this.state.forecastData)

OUTPUTS:  forecast is: ["11-06-2019", 52.5, 47.3, "sunny", "11-06-2019", 63.9, 39.7, "sunny", ...]
```

Referencing this.state.forecastData[2], for example, however was giving me errors.  So I checked the typeof this.state.forecast to see why and it says the array is an Object?  I need to further divide out the array data and manipulate it.  The first several items (e.x. forecastData[0] through forecastData[9] would be for the forecasted weather for 11-06-2019 at 3pm, ,6pm, 9pm so I need to pull those items, get the highest high and lowest low, etc.  I can't do that since I can't even reference the items in the array.

Things I've tried:
using Object.entries and Object.assign methods, but that just splits the items into several arrays, with the first item being the location number and the second item being the array item content.  I've tried manipulating the array within the component that uses it, but it still is an Object not an Array, so I can't reference the individual items.  The data set is large enough I don't think it would be best practice to push each of the 40+ items into their own state object key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Gaurav Roy!  You were partly correct.  The typeof didn't matter at all.  But the issue wasn't with the duration of my API, it was that my component was trying to render when it didn't have the data from the API call yet!  I put in a conditional

```
{this.state.forecast !== null && <Forecast forecast=this.state.forecastData />}
```

and got things working now.  Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript array is a subset of object , i'e it has the same prototype. So typeof Array will be an object. Thats not an issue. Can you update with the error which you are getting while accessing `this.state.forecastData[2]` coz what i . believe its something not with syntax , rather with the duration of API call.

I would recommend when accessing this.state.forecastData[2] first check if its length is greater than 0 , that way you are sure that there is data inside the array.

```
constructor(props){
forecastData:[]
}
```

and when you use it ,

```
if(this.state.forecastData.length > 0){
this.state.forecastData[2]
}
```

Try this, and revert with doubts.

Comment: Thank you! :-)  I got things working afterall, see other post for what I did.  Thanks again!